# I am searching for a way to save and read a file easily in python 3.5.2 (It doesn't need to be readable by humans.)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, save, writetofile

I am needing help with this as i am using it in part of my test and i would also like to use it to create a *save* *file* for a *python* game.

Comment: One word: `pickle`...

Comment: You wil have to elaborate your question. Please browse around for other questions to see how they are formulated - 

Also, readign and writting files in Python is part of the very basics of the language. Choosing a data format tosave yur data on, depends on what you need to be saved.

Comment: i am saving a list which contains str and i dont want to convert the entire list to an str

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested by Willem Van Onsem - take a look at `pickle` library. It is a standard library and u can use it to save objects into a file and load back later.